# Re-entering the UK on a visitor visa

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I got a visitor visa for 6 months with multiple entries, with the purpose of doing an interview with a UK company (they provided a document as proof). I visited the UK and had an interview, and everything went great.

Now, I would like to visit the UK (London) with a friend for a few days (3 months after the first visit) and was wondering whether I need a new visa since this one was issued for interviewing purposes, or I can enter with the visa I already have?

Thanks so much!

Comment: My guess is that you would likely be allowed to do so, since the purpose of the later visit falls under the allowed purposes for a visitor visa, and you were allowed multiple entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can visit UK again as long as your visa is valid.

*I was granted a visa for visiting a conference in Liverpool and visited UK three times after that (and there's no purpose of your visit printed on the visa anyway).*